# How to find installed tutorials?

Tags: ros, tutorial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
today installed my package manager some new packages for ROS.
As you can see there are new tutorials and myabe example files.
Let s take for istance the URDF tutorial in the picture:
[image: image description]
Where are saved? How to call those tutorials?

In the description there was no entry.

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190746/how-to-find-installed-tutorials?/) by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 893 on 2014-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Such packages you find them in `/opt/ros/indigo/share`
If you want to get the path for a specific package, say urdf_tutorials, you can type: `roscd urdf_tutorial/`

---

Originally posted by [emacsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3662/emacsd/) with karma: 194 on 2014-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any ROS package you install using a package manager (e.g., apt-get) will be installed in the default ROS installation path (which would normally be `/opt/ros/<distro>/`).

If you know the name of the package, just run:

```
$ rospack find <package_name>
```

The ROS tutorial [Navigating The Filesystem](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/NavigatingTheFilesystem) is a great source of information on how to use rosbash commands such as `rospack`.

Running nodes from those tutorial packages is exactly the same as running nodes from any other package.

---

Originally posted by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) with karma: 806 on 2014-08-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2